# Appium scrolling problem on screen with horizontal scrolling

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

This is a two stage problem.

The first problem is scrolling on an app via Appium. Previously, we had no issues scrolling on our app's home screen, but now the home screen features elements that have horizontal scrolling, the vertical scrolling functions we had inbuilt into our assertion methods are now failing (when searching for the chosen element to assert, they just don't scroll at all). Below is an example of the methods we have been using to find an element:

```
public WebElement findElementIdByScrolling(String textContains){
    wait(Constants.WaitTime);
    return driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"" + textContains + "\"));"));
```

I've been looking all over for a solution that works, but so far, no luck.

The second problem, is dependant on the first being solved. Not so much of a problem, but a question. How do you do horizontal scrolling on Appium? All element based scrolling I've seen involves scrolling down the screen instead of scrolling JUST an element vertically or horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code with in existing code `scrollable(true).instance(0))`

Add in desired capability UiAutomator2 if you are using appium as automation engine.

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
```

Now use below functions if you have element's id, and index as 0 for there is one element on page.

```
public void scrollByID(String Id, int index) {

        try {

             driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().resourceId(\""+Id+"\").instance("+index+"));")); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Scroll using Text**

```
public void scrollByText(String menuText) {

        try {

             driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textMatches(\"" + menuText + "\").instance(0));")); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Scroll with screen size:**

```
public void scrollToBottom() {

      int  x = driver.manage().window().getSize().width / 2;
      int start_y = (int) (driver.manage().window().getSize().height * 0.2);
      int end_y = (int) (driver.manage().window().getSize().height * 0.8);
        TouchAction dragNDrop = new TouchAction(driver)
                        .press(PointOption.point(x,start_y)).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(500)))
                        .moveTo(PointOption.point(x, end_y))
                        .release();
        dragNDrop.perform();
    }
```

Comment: Just tried this and it started scrolling up instead of down. Is there an adjustment I could make for this?

Comment: It will scroll to the element. If your element is up it will go up and down and look for element

Comment: The element is at the bottom of the page (off screen). It can't scroll to the element as it scrolls the other way when I run this.

Comment: Do you have multiple element with same Id? This is the case it will make it work differently else it works perfectly. If u have multiple element then you hv to give index value of the element

Comment: No, I checked in inspector. Just one element on that page with that ID.

Comment: Strange behavior!!! Do element  have some unique text or we have some text in bottom so we can scroll till bottom with the help of text? either we can scroll with help of screen size (last option)

Comment: It does indeed :)

What would I need to change in the method?

Comment: Thanks! Will try this tomorrow!

Comment: Sure. Try and let me know

Comment: Just tried that and it's STILL trying to scroll up instead of down.

Comment: Strange..ok let me edit the post. But you have to wait as it scroll up and down to look for text or element. Are you waiting till error appears

Comment: I have added scrolling function with the help of screen size.

Comment: Success! I managed to make it scroll to the bottom by swapping the values for start_y and end_y. Is there a way I can just make it scroll down one screen's worth instea of all the way to the bottom?

Comment: Good to hear. You can decrease the length of scroll. Now its 60% of screen means. .2 to .8 . Make “.5” in “end_y” so it will be 30% , .2 to .5

Comment: If this solution help you so please accept it as answer to help community.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers